# Winforms, ListView - stages of selection change

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'd like to implement a scenario that requires me to know if the user selects an item or deselects everything by clicking on an empty space. Basically, I need to keep the first item (which always exists) selected. It should be possible to select a different item, but as soon as the user clicks on empty space and when normally selection will be removed it should jump back to the first (default) item.

I tried to employ the selection changed events of the listview control, but those are triggered in a sequence which is not very helpful: first the currently selected item loses the selection. Then there's a separate event to indicate that a new item is selected.

The question is: when the event ItemSelectionChanged is triggered for the first time to say that a previously selected item is not selected any more, is it possible to know if that item was de-selected because another item is being selected or because nothing is selected?

Comment: The control should only get one input event (e.g. `MouseDown` or `KeyDown`), even though you get multiple `SelectionChanged` events. So you could use that to distinguish groups of `SelectionChanged` events that correspond to single user inputs. If you want more specific help, you should probably show a code example that is closest to what you want, explaining what it does, and how that's different from what you want to happen. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, I should have posted the solution closest to what I need, but to be honest I only had a naive straightforward attempt which was written in an assumption that the event fires once after the new state is established. And I removed it quite quickly while attempting to build something working, that's why. Otherwise, you're right of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to see if it can solve your problem. We remove the event callback to prevent the event to be called again, apply our logic, and re-assign the callback.

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.ItemSelectionChanged -= listView1_ItemSelectionChanged;

        if (!e.IsSelected)
        {
            listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
            listView1.Items[0].Focused = true;
        }
        else
        {
            listView1.Items[0].Selected = false;
            listView1.Items[e.ItemIndex].Selected = true;
        }

        listView1.ItemSelectionChanged += listView1_ItemSelectionChanged;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, but the results were strange. Sometimes two items would  end up selected. I didn't understand why, actually, and since I proceeded with an altogether different solution (see below), I didn't investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers.

I solved it altogether differently: upon a selection change event I enable a short timer which, when ticked, checks whether or not there's a selected item in the ListView, and if not, it selects the first one. And it disables itself in any case. Seems that it works for me, so I am stopping there.

Answer (score 0):

This will remember previous selection and keep it. (I needed it for my project and got some help here).

```
    private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        listView1.ItemSelectionChanged -= listView1_ItemSelectionChanged;
        if (!e.IsSelected)
        {
            temp = e.ItemIndex;
            listView1.Items[temp].Selected = true;
            listView1.Items[temp].Focused = true;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int y = listView1.Items.Count - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                listView1.Items[y].Selected = false;
            }
            listView1.Items[e.ItemIndex].Selected = true;
        }
        listView1.ItemSelectionChanged += listView1_ItemSelectionChanged;
    }
```